# How to add TextWatcher to Search Widget

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-search

I want to have a 'live' search using the `Android Search Widget`.  In other words, for each letter the user types I want a search to be performed.  I know I will be using `AsyncTask` to retrieve the results, but I am unsure how to get the continuous series of queries needed.

Right now I can only get a search query when the user hits `Go` on the keyboard.  If this were an `EditText`, I would simply add a `TextWatcher` to detect changes, but I do not know what to do for the `Search Widget`.

I have looked into [Searchable Configuration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html), and [Setting up the Search](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) on the Android development page but cannot find what I am looking for. Links and tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add a [OnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) to your SearchView via [setOnQueryTextListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener)), which [onQueryTextChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextChange(java.lang.String)) is called every time the input string changes.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out just before you posted (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

I dun goofed.

[SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

More specifically, get the `SearchView` as follows:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

and then set `setOnQueryTextListener`

Comment: Upvote for the first line of this answer. I love it when I, as the OP, dun goofed.